# Calling data from store in a normal Tab Panel

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.2

I'm trying to call 2 values from my store, and set it inside the `styles` in a `div` which I put it in a `html:` item. The store loads the data from a web API, which is working fine(I've tested using fiddler and the return response is correct) but I cant get the data in the store to work inside the html item.

Below is my view:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Main', {
   extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

   requires:['myapp.store.Style'],

   items: [
      {
         id: 'firstpage',
         title: 'Welcome',
         store: 'styleStore',
         styleHtmlContent: true,
         scrollable: true,

         items: [
            {
               html: ['<div id="testStr1" style="font-style:{FontStyle}; color:{Color};">',
                      'This is a test string.',
                      ' Go to the settings to change the style',
                      '</div>'
                    ].join("")
            }
            ]
        },
      }
   ]
}
```

My Store:

```
Ext.define('myapp.store.Styles', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

   requires:[
      'myapp.model.Style'
   ],

   config: {
      autoLoad: true,
      model: 'myapp.model.Style',
      storeId: 'styleStore',
      clearOnPageLoad:false,

      proxy:
      {
         type: 'ajax',
         listeners: {
         exception:{
            fn: function(pxy, response, operation, options){console.log("We've got a problem...");}
         }
      },

         url: 'http://localhost/styleapi/api/styles',
         reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
         }
      }
   }
});
```

My model:

```
Ext.define('myapp.model.Style', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields:[
        {
            name: 'Id',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'FontStyle'
        },
        {
            name: 'Color'
        },

    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://localhost/styleapi/api/styles'
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues here...

First, your main class, `myapp.view.Main`, is nesting items inside it, and those items are not configured correctly.  Your `items: ...` should be inside of `config`, and there should be an `xtype` for each item, if you want the item to not be the default type of `container`.  In your current code, you have an `items: ..` config on your first item, where you are putting `html`.  This results in a nested component, which is not what you are intending here.

In addition, you are using `html`, when you really want to use a template.  When you have a fixed set (or object) of data, you can use a `component` with `tpl` and `data`; when using a `store` for the data, you would use a `dataview` with an `itemTpl` config, which will repeat that template for each item in the store.  Currently, your top-level item is defaulting to a `container`, where you are using a `store` config, which won't do anything at the moment.

So, steps to fix:

1. Move the top-level item into `config` property
2. Change the top-level item to be a `dataview`
3. Move the `html` out of the nested item and into an `itemTpl` property as an XTemplate (i.e. `itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div ...')`)

Comment: 1. sorry about that, i totally missed that out. Thanks for highlighting it. 
2. I need to use tab.panel since i have another panel where the codes are inside the same file. I did some lookup in the sencha docs by using xtype declaration, but it still doesnt work. My code as below:
                    {
                        xtype: 'dataview',
                        store: 'styleStore',
                        itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('test: {Color}'),
                    }

Comment: Update, got it! Thanks man. The previous changes doesn't work because I was still declaring the 'xtype' inside an item, not at the top level. I was a bit confuse there. :P BTW, just a question though, why should we use the 'Ext.XTemplate'? I still don't quite get that one. Thanks anyway!.